# Failed to resolve compile 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT' in android

Tags: android

I am using active android library and i am getting the error **" failed to resolve compile 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT' "** 
   My project level build gradle is given below:-

```
 mavenCentral()
     maven { url https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
```

and app level build.gradle is

```
 dependencies {compile 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
        compile files('libs/ActiveAndroid-3.3.jar')}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Syfer  question has been explained above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the solution of this problem.Go to project level gradle and do the following.Add the two lines in

```
allprojects {
repositroies {
mavenCentral() 
maven{
url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" 
} 
jcenter()
```

AND THEN GO TO YOUR APP level gradle.build and do the following

```
compile 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
```

Answer (score 5):

Do the needfull steps
1) remove or comment following line from build.gradle file
  implementation 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
2)    Download jar.                                                                                                                                 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EfsPM4h9KkApt9qNCZH7W2Hjz0ViXhuj/view
3) Add jar to lib folder
4)  add implementation files('libs/activeandroid-3.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar') line to build.gradle file
It works for me

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you added below in your **App Level** `build.gradle` Section

```
  repositories 
  {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
  }
```

**Then**

App Level **`build.gradle`** Section

```
compile 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
```

**Structure**

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
 android {
    compileSdkVersion //
    buildToolsVersion '//'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "//"
        minSdkVersion //
        targetSdkVersion /
        multiDexEnabled true

        repositories 
        {
            mavenCentral()
            maven {url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        }

    }
    buildTypes 
    {
     .....
     }

}

dependencies 
    {
      compile 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'

    }
```

Comment: I used the same but not working showing error when i build the application.

Comment: @GyanSwaroopAwasthi Restart your IDE

Comment: @GyanSwaroopAwasthi What about this answer

Comment: @SandeepSingh Glad to hear.